# Display relational data through a loop in R markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have forest inventory data stored in multiple relational tables. I would like to create a report in markdown that displays information in line with the data’s relational hierarchy. Namely:

```
Plot 1
    Subplot 1
        Tree 1
        Tree 2
        Tree 3
Plot 1 
    Subplot 2
        Tree 1
        Tree 2
        Tree 3 (and so on…)
```

The code shown below reprints the all subplot data together. However, I would like each subplot in individual tables (I am using [knitr](https://yihui.name/knitr/)) so then i can add the addition tree attributes under their respective subplots. My issue can be reproduced with the code below:

````
# Define Plot Number

```{r}
call_plot <- 1
```



```{r echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
# Make the df plot_info
plot_id <- c(1:3)
x <- c(89.74, 89.67, 89.62)
y <- c(22.71, 22.66, 22.71)
plot_info <- as.data.frame(cbind(plot_id, x, y))

# Make the df subplot_info
plot_id <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
subplot_id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
subplot_info <- as.data.frame(cbind(plot_id, subplot_id))

# Make the df for tree 
plot_id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
         2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
subplot_id <- c(4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
            5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5)

species <- c("Phoenix sylvestris", "Albizia procera", "Tamarindus indica", 
         "Lannea coromandelica", "Lannea coromandelica", "Cocos nucifera",  
         "Cocos nucifera", "Samanea saman", "Samanea saman", "Cocos nucifera", 
         "Swietenia mahagoni", "Gmelina arborea", "Mangifera indica", "Mangifera 
         indica", "Cocos nucifera", "Cocos nucifera", "Samanea saman", "Mangifera 
         indica", "Artocarpus heterophyllus", "Artocarpus heterophyllus", "Artocarpus 
         heterophyllus", "Cocos nucifera", "Cocos nucifera", "Swietenia mahagoni", 
         "Cocos nucifera", "Samanea saman", "Polyalthia longifolia", "Samanea saman", 
         "Dillenia indica")

tree <- as.data.frame(cbind(plot_id, subplot_id, species))
```


```{r latex_table, results='markup', echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

# Asign call_plot
plot_info <- plot_info[which(plot_info$plot_id == call_plot),]
# Print Plot table
knitr::kable(plot_info,  table.attr = "id=\"mytable\"", caption = "Plot Location")

#Asign subplot data to plot table 
subplot_info <- subplot_info[which(subplot_info$plot_id == plot_info$plot_id),]

# Loop through subplots
for (i in 1:length(unique(subplot_info$subplot_id))){ 

p = (knitr::kable(subplot_info,  table.attr = "id=\"mytable\"", caption = "Subplot"));

print(p)
}
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your loop 'for'. If I understand correctly you want to display tree information but call the table subplot_info. Check if this works:

add tree_id column in the tree dataframe:

```
tree_id <- 1:length(subplot_id)

tree <- as.data.frame(cbind(plot_id, subplot_id, tree_id, species))
```

then change your loop for (# loop through subplot) with:

```
# loop through subplot
vec_plot_id <- unique(tree$plot_id)
vec_subplot_id <- unique(tree$subplot_id)
for (i in 1:length(vec_plot_id)){
  for (j in 1:length(vec_subplot_id)){

    table_tree <- tree[which(tree$plot_id == vec_plot_id[i] & tree$subplot_id == vec_subplot_id[j]),]
    table_tree[,c("plot_id", "subplot_id")] <- NULL

    caption = paste("plot id: ", vec_plot_id[i], ", subplot id: ", vec_subplot_id[j])

    p = (knitr::kable(table_tree,  table.attr = "id=\"mytable\"", caption = caption))

    print(p)
   }
}
```

Hope This help!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @David